# How can I compare SQL entries with the same beginning and different endings?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, the rows I'm looking to compare are formatted somewhat like this: 
 [Form Code]_[Version Date (mm/yy)].

When forms are updated, they use the same code, but change the version date to reflect when it goes into effect.  So you might see Example_Code_12_01, and then it gets replaced with Example_Code_12_17.

What I'm trying to do is write a SQL Server query that will loop through every one of these forms, all with varying Form Codes, and return two forms with the same code but different version dates.

I was thinking it would be kind of along these lines:

```
select a.FullFormName, b.FullFormName
from Forms a
join Forms b on --here is where the logic for the compare would go--
where a.FullFormName != b.FullFormName
--The above is to make sure it doesn't return the same exact form twice
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: If you know, how many characters you want to compare, you could use LEFT or SUBSTRING like described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @ D Shih - Let's say I have five forms in the data set below.  It would loop through and only return the first two, because they are both AB_01_01, but two different versions.  Gordon Linoff's query below appears to be turning up the right info.  I may need to tweak it a bit to account for some more information I need to collect, but it's got the comparison I need.

AB_01_01_01_05
AB_01_01_05_16
CD_01_01_01_12
AB_06_28_01_11
JJ_72_01_01_05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want to make the comparison without the last 6 characters:

```
select a.FullFormName, b.FullFormName
from Forms a join
     Forms b
     on left(a.FullFormName, len(a.FullFormName) - 6) = left(b.FullFormName, len(b.FullFormName) - 6)  --here is where the logic for the compare would go--
where a.FullFormName <> b.FullFormName;
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like its working.  Some of the forms in my system have suffixes after the version dates, but this will suffice for now.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Instead of putting Left function in join Condition, we can use Computed Columns because if indexes are available for those columns then the SQL Optimizer will not use Indexes.

Comment: @RGS . . . Computed columns with indexes is definitely a good solution for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the form follows `VersionCode_mm_yy`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX('_',Code,1)) IN 
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX('_',Code,1)) 
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX('_',Code,1))
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT (Code)) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this query isn’t trivially easy to write is because the data structure you described violates first normal form. You have a form code and a version combined into a single column. I’m not sure if you have the flexibility to modify the schema, but if you do, you should consider separating these two values into two different columns. With this change, you can simply join on the form codes being equal.

If you can’t change the schema, but you can make temp tables, you might consider parsing those two values into two separate columns in a temp table if you have a lot of to work through. If you write an inner join comparing substrings on both sides, you are effectively removing any ability for SQL Server to use any indexes you may have. The query is pretty much guaranteed to run at O(n^2) with n being the number of records in your Forms table. If the table has only a few records, you won’t notice it. If it has a lot, it will be very slow.